Angular -Access route param require input in tests when using using with component input binding
I am using Angular 18 with Angular testing library: my issues is that I am able access route param as required input signal. However when I run the tests that depends on this input it's complaining that Input is required but no value available yet error.
How to provide this to My test in ATL so I can use the input.

Create a mock ParamMap that simulates route parameters, then create a mock ActivatedRoute that returns the  mock ParamMap as an Observable.
Using this approach you can test both the initial route parameter binding and parameter changes (by calling next with a new ParamMap on paramMapSubject and then calling fixture.detectChanges())
  const paramMapSubject = new Subject<ParamMap>();

  const createParamMap = (id: string): ParamMap => ({
    get: (param: string) => param === 'id' ? id : null,
    getAll: (param: string) => param === 'id' ? [id] : [],
    has: (param: string) => param === 'id',
    keys: ['id']
  });

  async function setup() {
    return render(ExampleComponent, {
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            paramMap: paramMapSubject.asObservable()
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }

